# Determine the process name of a Manifest-registered Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a client that binds a service.

This client should wait 5 seconds asynchronously to bind the service, unless the process that the service lives inis already alive.

To determine if the process is alive, it is necessary to determine what process the service would exist in, should it be created. The process is defined using the "process" attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file inside of the service declaration.

This client and service are API packages, so they can be built into any app. The service therefore may be registered with a given name and packageName. However, the caller to the client should not need to provide the process which is being used, for my usecase.

I am able to retrieve all ServiceInfo associated to the phone, but it does not seem to contain the process information within it.

I am able to easily determine if the service is alive, which guarantees that the process is alive, however it is possible that the process is alive and the service is not. One solution would be for the process to use the client to bind the service in its own process, but this uses more resources so I would like to avoid it. Here is how I can figure out if my service is alive:

```
val componentName = ComponentName("packageName", "serviceName")
val isServiceProcessAlive: Boolean = try {
  (context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
    .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .firstOrNull { it.service == componentName } != null
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    false
  }
```

Is the following possible:

Given a serviceName and packageName, is it possible to determine the associated service's process attribute, that is, what process it exists in, should it be created.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is possible to get the process name from ServiceInfo.

ServiceInfo extends ComponentInfo, which has a public processName field.

With the process name from the ServiceInfo, you can then iterate all running processes and find a match.

```
  val componentName = ComponentName("packageName", "serviceName")
  val isServiceProcessAlive: Boolean = try {
    context
      .packageManager
      .getServiceInfo(componentName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
      .processName
      .let { processName ->
        (context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
          .runningAppProcesses
          .firstOrNull { runningAppProcessInfo -> runningAppProcessInfo.processName == processName } != null
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      false
    }
```